# How to use multiple index.js files/cloud functions on firestore functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function which is checking the count value which is a field inside a doc which is inside a collection of "boys". On change of count, the cloud function performs some operation.
I want to have a similar cloud function but for another collection by the name "girls". How can I deploy another function to the cloud functions as right now, it is just letting me upload one by replacing the older function?

```
exports.updatingCount = functions.firestore
  .document('boys/{count}')
  .onWrite((snap) => {//The current function with my code here})
```

I want a similar function like this but can't find how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the same Cloud Function with a different name for girls:

```
exports.updatingCountForGirls = functions.firestore
  .document('girls/{count}')
  ...
```

Or you can go for a more flexible approach with a fully variable path:

```
exports.updatingCount = functions.firestore
  .document('{collectionPath}/{count}')
  ...
```

and check the value of `collectionPath` in the Cloud Function.

Comment: Yes I had solved it but thanks a lot.